# Read result of Promise - Buffer from decoded audio

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to get an audio file from an assets folder and play the decoded audio in the web. I want to use the web audio API so I can apply visuals based on the audio data.

Currently my code is:

```
      let audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  let masterGainNode = audioContext.createGain();
  let songBuffer = null;
  let path = "../assets/sampleTrackForWeb.mp3";

  function fetchSong() {
    fetch(path)
      .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then((arrayBuffer) =>
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(
          arrayBuffer,
          (audioBuffer) => {
            console.log(audioBuffer) // the audio buffer is here and ready to go!
            songBuffer = audioBuffer;
          },
          (error) => console.error(error)
        )
      );
  }

  fetchSong();

  console.log(songBuffer); // null???!!!
```

I am following almost exactly from the MDN docs on how to do this. Any help is appreciated! :)

EDIT: Posting the MDN docs on how they do it

```
var source;
function getData() {
  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'viper.ogg', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  request.onload = function() {
    var audioData = request.response;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        source.buffer = buffer;

        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.loop = true;
      },

      function(e){ console.log("Error with decoding audio data" + e.err); });

  }

  request.send();
}
```

Comment: Just like asking someone to go get buy some matches by asking immediately afterwards - where are the matches. Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await -  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan web audio api doesn't support promise based syntax for decodingAudioData on safari which is what im using

Comment: Fetch Song!--Gimme buffer!--- ... --- > song fetched. *"Why is buffer Null"*? Are you saying fetch does not relies on Promises? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: OK I get that fetch is asynchronous that's why I have the .then() to await the response. But the buffer is there in the callback. Why is the audioBuffer not being stored into the songBuffer memory slot?

Comment: By the same reason this won't work: `let a; setTimeout(() => (a = "Albatros"), 1000 ); console.log(a); // why is a not an Albatros` - If you place `console.log(songBuffer);` **inside** the *thennable* callback, what do you get in console? The ArrayBuffer, right? That means, if you want to `await` for it - than await for it.

Comment: Ok, maybe I am confused on what needs to be changed in my code then. I have pasted the docs on how they fetch songs using XML requests, all I really changed was moving to a standard fetch request.

Comment: Also, simply adding,   await fetchSong()      throws an error

Answer (score 3):

**The issue:**
you're *synchronously* expecting a *result* ahead of time.  Just like doing:

```js
let A;
setTimeout(() => (A = "Albatros"), 1000);
console.log(A); // undefined  
// ...Why is A not an Albatros?
```

### Promise

Learn about **Promises** to dive deeper into asynchronicity:

- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Promise.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)
- [Async, Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)
- [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (also returns a Promise)

---

From  [MDN decodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData)

> *The decodeAudioData() method of the BaseAudioContext Interface is used to asynchronously decode audio file data contained in an ArrayBuffer. In this case the ArrayBuffer is loaded from XMLHttpRequest and FileReader. The decoded AudioBuffer is resampled to the AudioContext's sampling rate,* **then passed to a callback or promise**.

So let's explore how to *pass it to a **callback** or **promise***:

### **Promise.then()**

You could chain your Promises with `.then()`.
Since `.then()` returns a Promise, that allows to *promisify* the returned result of  `decodeAudioData`:

```js
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
const fetchSong = (path) =>
    fetch(path)
        .then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())
        .then((arrayBuffer) => audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer));
```

### Async Await

**or** by using the *sugary* **Async Await** syntax:

```js
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
const fetchSong = async (path) => {
    const xhr = await fetch(path);
    const arrayBuffer = await xhr.arrayBuffer();
    return audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
};
```

Both the above examples **return a Promise**, and can therefore be used like:

```js
const songDataPromise = fetchSong("test.mp3");   // Promise {<pending>}
songDataPromise.then((audioBuffer) => {
    console.log(audioBuffer);                    // AudioBuffer {}
    console.log(audioBuffer.getChannelData(0));  // Float32Array []
});
```

### Callback

To resolve all in-time, just chain another `.then()` to the set - and pass its result to a **callback** function:

```js
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
const fetchSong = (path, cb) =>
    fetch(path)
        .then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())
        .then((arrayBuffer) => audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
        .then(cb);  // Resolve with callback

fetchSong("test.mp3", (audioBuffer) => {
    console.log(audioBuffer);                   // AudioBuffer {}
    console.log(audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)); // Float32Array []
});
```

Comment: I have filed two PRs with MDN, one to update the docs page and the other to add a new promise-based example page using code based on this answer.  I'll let y'all know if/when it has gone live.